# Unable to properly integrate infinispan jcache libraries with wildfly 18

Tags: wildfly, infinispan, jcache

I'm following the guidelines on the [latest infispan 11.0 doc](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#jcache_jsr_107)

So I did:

1. Installed infinispan libraries under wildfly modules directory
2. Added dependencies on pom.xml

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-cachestore-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-cdi-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

...

```
    <plugins>
        <!--Configure the EJB plugin: we create EJB 3.2. If not specified, an error will arise because the plugin expects an Ejb-jar by default. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Tell Maven we are using EJB 3.2 -->
                <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.infinispan:ispn-11.0 services</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I tried to use @CacheResult annotation on a service method, but all I got is this error:

```
 javax.cache.CacheException: No CachingProviders have been configured
```

I guess I need to to add jcache libraries on manifest, but I'm not sure and neither I don't know how.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

A bit "late to the party", but I was facing a similar issue but seem to got it working by not only including the `org.infinispan` module, but also the modules `org.infinispan.jcache` and `org.infinispan.cdi.embedded`.

In addition, I ran into the issue described in [JCache with Infinispan in Wildfly 14 generate Unsatisfied dependencies for type InfinispanExtensionEmbedded with qualifiers @Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619067/jcache-with-infinispan-in-wildfly-14-generate-unsatisfied-dependencies-for-type) (Unsatisfied dependencies for type InfinispanExtensionEmbedded), so I had to add the `export` keyword to the modules.

My complete classpath now looks like this:

```
org.infinispan:ispn-11.0 services export,org.infinispan.jcache:ispn-11.0 services export,org.infinispan.cdi.embedded:ispn-11.0 services export
```

Also, the following tutorial has been helpful for me: [Sergii Kostenko's Blog: Distributed caching with Wildfly/Infinispan and poor JCache support](https://kostenko.org/blog/2020/08/wildfly-infinspan.html)

EDIT:
[It seems that this is definitely unsupported by JBoss EAP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/configuring_high_availability#clustering_modes). So I would assume the same to be true for WildFly:

> **Important**
> Infinispan is delivered as a private module in JBoss EAP to
> provide the caching capabilities of JBoss EAP. Infinispan is not
> supported for direct use by applications.